# Написание письма

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно и грамотно написать письмо: "Сообщаем Вам о том что на объекте.... 27.08.2012 и 28.08.2012 года не было подачи электроэнергии, в связи с чем были приостановлены работы, а так же отсутствуют плиты перекрытия и песок для подготовки засыпки полов. В письме от 20.08.2012 года были предоставлены потребность железобетонных изделий и строительных материалов  для строительно-монтажных работ, но ответа с вашей стороны не было. В связи с этим мы отстаем от графика. Убедительно просим Вас решить вопрос в кротчайшие сроки".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В варианте, который предложил уважаемый Fuchoin Kazuki, я исправил бы еще ошибки, где союз "также" почему-то написан раздельно,а слово "КРАТЧАЙШИЕ" - через "о" в корне.Другие корректировки связаны со словоупотреблением (потребность вместо необходимость, убрать повтор "строительных") 
    Сообщаем Вам о том, что на объекте.... 27.08.2012 и 28.08.2012 года не было подачи электроэнергии, в связи с чем были приостановлены работы, а ТАКЖЕ отсутствуют плиты перекрытия и песок для (ПОДГОТОВКИ - я убрал бы это лишнее слово) засыпки полов. В письме от 20.08.2012 года были предоставлены данные о ПОТРЕБНОСТИ в железобетонных изделиях и ДРУГИХ  материалах для строительно-монтажных работ, но ответа с Вашей стороны не было. В связи с этим мы отстаем от графика. Убедительно просим Вас решить вопрос в  КРАТЧАЙШИЕ  сроки".